# justifyContent not applying in View React Native

Tags: android, css, react-native, view, flexbox

For some reason in this view the justify Content tag does not apply in my view ? I have tried applying it in the modalScreen view but that does not work either. Any ideas ?

```
function BottomPopup() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.modalScreen}>
      <View style={styles.topbar}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="arrow-left" size={24} color="black" />
        <Text>Create Post</Text>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="content-save" size={24} color="black" />
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>hey</Text>
        <Text>hey</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalScreen: {
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  topbar: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
  },
});
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Do you want the Topbar like 

Image <Spaces > Create Post <Spaces> Image
?? like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```js
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalScreen: {
    flex:1,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
  },
  topbar: {
    width: width,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    backgroundColor: "green",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **flex:1** in modalScreen style like [Snack.IO](https://snack.expo.io/eUxCTbclm)

Answer (score 0):

I had to add width: "100%" and then it worked